# адресная арифметика с++ и онлайн компиляторы

Tags: c++

извиняюсь за нубский вопрос: при обьявлении и инициализации переменных - как происходит восприятие указателем или онлайн-компилятором их адреса? Поясню
к примеру int x=1,y=2,z=3;

допустим, у меня *ptr указывает на x, если вызвать *(ptr+1) (или иногда *(ptr-1))- он не всегда укажет на y.

Но если сначала вывести адрес переменной, т.е. std::cout<<&y, допустим (и он в большинстве онлайн компиляторов идет последовательно рядом с х). То *(ptr+1) укажет на y, понятное дело, ведь адрес будет последовательным после х!

Т.е. при проверке адреса указатель только тогда понимает, куда указывать? или компилятор только тогда узнает (или присваивает) адрес?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: А кто гарантирует, что объявленные рядом разные переменные занимают соседние адреса??

Comment: Я один ничерта не понел?...

Comment: никто, но на именно компиляторах, которыми я пользуюсь, адреса были выведены несколько раз подряд для проверки - всегда отличались на +4 или -4.
Ерунда с разыменованием начинается, когда адрес не выводился.

Comment: Т.е. когда вы выодите адрес,  то  y распологается рядом, а когда не выводите, то по другому адресу?..

Comment: Адреса может и не быть, Например, компилятор может вообще убрать неиспользуемую переменную.

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, возможно и так! при выводе адреса птр+1 -этот адрес отличался на 4 после или перед х. но значение вроде как мусор.

при выводе адреса у (перед разыменованием или после - неважно), адрес шел последовательно и птр правильно указывал на него.

Comment: Адреса глобальных и статических локальных переменных известны после компиляции и линковки (если они существуют, как Yaant указал), обычных локальных  - нет, они становятся актуальными после входа в функцию. Не стоит заниматься ерундой, полагаясь на недокументированные особенности.

Comment: Если вам так уж надо что б x,y,z были в одной связке - создайте структуру, и доставайте их из структуры.`struct {int x,y,z;} d`; Тогда адреса будут зарезервированы.

Comment: Не понятно при чему тут вообще онлайн компиляторы. Онлайн компиляторы по сути ничем не отличаются от оффлайн компиляторов. Это такие же компиляторы, только где-то на сервере, а не у вас на компьютере.

Answer (score 1):

Если *"*ptr указывает на x"*, то при вызове `*(ptr+1)` или `*(ptr-1)` получается неопределенное поведение, так как разыменовываемый указатель является невалидным.